# pre-commit hook validating c++ code

Tags: c++, svn, pre-commit-hook

Today I've updated our repository and tried to recompile it (it's a c++ application). It doesn't compile. My first reaction was to kill my coworker, but because I can't do it I need to find another solution.

Is it possibile to prevent to commit code that doesn't compile? We have a Makefile and what the pre-commit hook need to do it's simpy to check the output status of the command make. Is it right?

How in pratice can I implement it (I've never work with svn hook)?

Comment: Setup a build server that builds the tree once an hour.  Whomever breaks the build gets to do the dishes or wear the dunce cap for a day.

Comment: @Hans: I need a simpler solution

Comment: Erm, okay, the breaker has to buy beer on Friday.  A build server really *is* a trivial solution to this problem.  Items 2 and 3 on Joel's 12 Steps to Better Code: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

Comment: A build server is the simpler solution.

Comment: as the others said: don't implement it with hooks. If a commit takes 20 seconds because there's something being compiled in the background, you will go crazy. Take a build server and let it do the work for you. Example one is hudson: http://hudson-ci.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right in principle. However, it will likely cause major delays in committing (unless your application compiles in under a second). So you should really look for a different approach, where it lets users commit, but than starts a build process right away, and sends out email if it fails to build.

One way of doing that is [buidbot](http://trac.buildbot.net/).

Comment: it compile and create an excutable it 30 seconds. I think that with the appropriate flags in gcc (for example -gnats as goreSplatter said) I can reduce to a resonable time.

Comment: +1 we have a code base that takes almost an hour to build. But even if it took only 20 seconds, I would consider the delay on the commit unacceptable. A build server is the way to go, and that's what we use. You can always run one locally on your dev box if you don't have the authority/influence to get an official one set up.